# Controller initiated twice on state transition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a simple search app. The search result page is defined as:

```
.state('search', {
    url: '/search?q',
    templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
    controller: 'SearchCtrl'
})
```

And in `SearchCtrl`, I have two scope functions to add/remove search terms:

```
$scope.searchByTerm = function(term) {
    termsService.addTerm($scope.selectedTerms, term);
    $state.go($state.current, {q: $scope.selectedTerms}, {reload: true});
};

 $scope.removeTerm = function(term) {
    termsService.removeTerm($scope.selectedTerms, term);
    $state.go($state.current, {q: $scope.selectedTerms}, {reload: true});
 };
```

The `termsService.addTerm` function simply pushes `term` into `$scope.selectedTerms` array, and `termsService.removeTerm` removes `term` from the array if it exists. Since I want the page to reload and fetch data according to new search terms, I have set `reload` to be true.

With this, the `SearchCtrl` sometimes gets initiated twice, mostly when `$scope.selectedTerms` has 2 or more items. I've tried all possible ways of rewriting this, and it still consistently runs twice.

If I remove the `termsService` line in both functions, the state transition wouldn't initiate `SearchCtrl` twice.

Can't figure out what can possibly go wrong...

(angular-ui-router#0.2.11, angular#1.2.26)

Comment: Check that your view doesn't have `ng-controller="SearchCtrl"`

Comment: There's really not enough information here to answer your question, and in most cases, "X is bugged but when I do an unrelated Y it suddenly starts working" is a misdiagnosis. What you should do instead is provide a working example(check out http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f) of your problem.

Comment: can you share view/search.html

Comment: @NewDev Thanks, I have checked that and I'm sure it doesn't.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1484 this is a bug in 0.2.11